# Calculate the next volume with triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying and I've seen the next question:

Calculate the volume of:
$\ V=\{(x, y, z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 2x, z\ge\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}\} $

Things I've tried:

1. analyzing the figures (sphere / one side cone).
2. moving to polar/sphere coordinates.

I will be glad for directions on how to solve this question.
Thanks.

Comment: I think it is easier if we use sperical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. By considering the projection onto the $xy$-plane of the intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2x$ (centred at $(1,0,0)$ of radius $1$) and the surface of the upper cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is given by the closed curve $x^2+y^2=x$ which is a circle centred at $(1/2,0)$ of radius $1/2$. Hence
$$V=\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq x}\left(\int_{z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2-y^2}}1dz\right)dxdy.$$
Switching to polar coordinates we get
$$V=2\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{\cos(\theta)}
\left(\sqrt{2r\cos(\theta)-r^2}-r\right)rdr d\theta.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking about this. I'll let you know

Comment: @kfiros Have you the answer of this exercise? It should be $(3\pi-8)/9$.

Comment: Hey @Robert, I got your method! Thank you very much! I don't have the answer for this question, however, I got (3pi-4)/9.

Comment: @kfiros Well done!! BTW please take a few seconds for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour